# AWS Lambda API endpoints domain not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The recent addition of API endpoints to Lambda was great news but the generated endpoints don't resolve and hence can't be triggered.

When I call the endpoint I get the following.

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Anyone else experiencing this and have a solution?

Comment: This is currently a bug in the `API Gateway` Lambda integration in the dashboard. You can find correct URLs in the `API Gateway` dashboard in your deployed API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting Amazon support turns out there is a bug in the generation of the endpoint, below is the quote from support.

> The issue you are seeing has been raised internally and the Lambda
>   team has been notified of the issue.  There is a bug in the way that
>   the URL is generated on the Lambda API endpoint page.  The region and
>   'execute-api' parts of the URL have to be switched around and
>   .amazonaws has to be added.  So instead of
>
> https://i9ng3vkc9b.eu-west-1.execute-api.com/prod/putme
>
> try
>
> https://i9ng3vkc9b.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/putme
>
> The correct URL is shown when you create a new endpoint, and when you
>   look at the API from the API Gateway Console page.  I apologize for
>   the confusion that the bug has caused, it will be fixed shortly.